# Number of subfields of a given field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a field with $5^{12}$ elements. What is the total number of proper subfields of $F$?

A) $3$ B) $6$ C) $8$ D) $5$

Explain the concept used to solve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$512=2^9$. So a subfield has $2^k$ elemet with $k\mid9$. What is the number of positive divisors of $9$?

If it is $5^{12}$. Then same. What is the number of positive divisors of $12$?

Moreover, since it say proper, we will get $-1$ of the above.

Comment: Sir i know this is old post but i have a doubt ! why k have to be divisor of 9 ?